# State not updating with react redux thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm a bit new to using redux and react. I'm trying to make a simple API call with redux and having it render in react. I can see the API call working as it's in the payload in redux dev tools, but I can't seem to get it to update the state possibly in the `connect?.

`actions/index`

```
import FilmAPI from '../api/api';

export const FETCH_FILMS = 'FETCH_FILMS';
export const RECEIVE_FILMS = 'RECEIVE_FILMS';

export const receiveFilms = (films) => {
  return {
    type: RECEIVE_FILMS,
    films
  };
}

    export const fetchFilmsRequest = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios.get('https://www.snagfilms.com/apis/films.json?limit=10')
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(receiveFilms(response.data))
      })
  }
}

export default fetchFilmsRequest;
```

`reducers/FilmReducer`

```
import RECEIVE_FILMS from '../actions/index';

export function films (state = [], action) {
 switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_FILMS:
      return [...state, action.films];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

`reducers/index`

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { films } from './FilmsReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  films,
});
```

`containers/FilmListContainer`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchFilmsRequest } from '../actions';
import FilmList from '../components/FilmList'

class FilmListContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchFilmsRequest();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FilmList films={this.props.films}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  films: state.films
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchFilmsRequest: fetchFilmsRequest})(FilmListContainer);
```

`configureStore.js`

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    const composeEnhancers =
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ?
            window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
                // options like actionSanitizer, stateSanitizer
            }) : compose;

    const enhancer = composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    );

    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        enhancer
    );
}
```

As mentioned, Redux DevTools show the films in the payload, but films still remain 0 in its state. Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you ever figure out the solution? New to Redux and banging my head

Answer (score 1):

You can get updated state by subscribing store and use `store.getState()`

**Steps:**

1. Write subscribe function in constructor of component class.
2. Set state of class by `store.getState()`.

import store from '../js/store/index';

class MyClass extends Component {

constructor(props, context) {

```
 super(props, context);

 this.state = {

        classVariable: ''

 }
 store.subscribe(() => {

    this.setState({

    classVariable: store.getState().MyStoreState.storeVariable

    });

 });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are close, your action needs to send the data to the store by dispatching an event which your reducer can then catch. This is done using the `type` attribute on the dispatch object.

https://redux.js.org/basics/actions

```
return fetch('https://www.snagfilms.com/apis/films.json?limit=10')
  .then(response => {
    dispatch({
      type: RECEIVE_FILMS,
      payload: response,
    })
  })
```

You then need to grab the data in your reducer and put it in the store

```
export function films (state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_FILMS:
      return { 
        ...state,
        films: action.payload.films
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: First, thank you! I've tried what you've suggested but unfortunately, there's still nothing. `this.props.films` still remain 0.

Comment: Does it get added to the Redux Store? If you don't already have one, install a browser extension which will be a great help for you when debugging

Comment: I believe it does. I'm using Redux Devtools. It's showing data in the payload, but still, films doesn't seem to populate. `this.props` returns `{films: Array(0), fetchFilmsRequest: ƒ}`

Answer (score 0):

Just dispatch result of resolved `fetch` promise like so:

if the payload is json, then:

```
export const fetchFilmsRequest = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    return fetch('https://www.snagfilms.com/apis/films.json?limit=10')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({
          type: RECEIVE_FILMS,
          payload: response
        })
      })
  }
```

Your reducer would need modifying slightly to:

```
export function films (state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_FILMS:
      return [...action.payload]; // assuming response is jus array of films
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this approach and have the film data in the payload, but the state doesn't update still. `this.props` returns `{films: Array(0), fetchFilmsRequest: ƒ}`

Comment: does it go into your reducer? can you log payload in there? are you calling `createStore` somewhere?

Comment: I tried logging payload and it returns `undefined`? I'll update my post with my `createStore`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to import your action type constant into your reducer using a named import instead of a default export.

i.e. `import {RECEIVE_FILMS} from '../actions'` rather than `import RECEIVE_FILMS from '../actions'`

Comment: In other words, your reducer is being dispatched, but it's never falling into that case statement because it's importing the async request and comparing that against the action type, which is a string.

Comment: And as others suggested, you'll need to actually dispatch your `receiveFilms` action exactly where you have your comment to do so. `dispatch(receiveFilms(response))`

Comment: I am having this same issue and have everything configured as mentioned. My state is updated when I fetch for the current user but the store is not triggering a refresh. When I view in redux I auth being populated with the user details.